# JQGrid - How to populate a column in jqgrid as dropdown and textbox in edit mode

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to Jqgrid. in my form i need to populate JQgrid columns with inline row edit option. Also there is a checkbox in form.

in edit mode , Column should be dropdown list if a checkbox is checked else it should be textbox.

i am using editOptions: {value : fnOption()} to populate column with all option values in row edit mode.

how can i change this column to textbox if checkbox is unchecked?